# Prometheus scrape multiple exporter located in same host at same time

Tags: prometheus

I got into a problem which is I want to scrape some exporter on same host.

#### Detail:

**My setup is like this:**
`Exporters(VM#3/4/5)` are in a private network, so I have to use a proxy to get the data. And the proxy's address is `http://10.0.0.1`, All `Exporter` are running the same code, so they exports the same metrics data.

```
   VM#1           VM#2                         VM#3
+---------|     +------------+    Proxy    +------------+
| Grafana | <-- | Prometheus | <---------- | Exporter#1 | 
+---------|     +------------+   ^ ^       +------------+
                                 | |
                                 | |         VM#4
                                 | |      +------------+
                                 | +----- | Exporter#2 |
                                 |        +------------+
                                 |           VM#5
                                 +------- +------------+
                                          | Exporter#3 |
                                          +------------|
```

**And here's my scrape config:**

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: "myJob"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    scrape_timeout: 5s
    metrics_path: "/metrics"
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ "10.0.0.1" ]
```

#### Now here's the problem:

**How can I tell prometheus scrape all three `Exporter` at the same time in the same `scrape_config`? I've tried using `params` like below(added a param called `exporter_url` in the proxy server so it can route the request to different exporter) but not help, it seems like params will be overide rather than different request for each param**

```
- job_name: "myJob"
    scrape_interval: 5s
    scrape_timeout: 5s
    metrics_path: "/metrics"
    params:
        exporter_url: ["exporter1", "exporter2", "exporter3"]
    static_configs:
      - targets: [ "10.0.0.1" ]
```

All three `Exporter` are running the same code, So I want to include them all in single `scrape_config`, I know I can write different `scrape_config` for each `Exporter`. Is my goal achieveable? Or I have to write different `scrape_config`?

Answer (score 3):

You can either create different job entries for the different exporters, or, instead, you can add the IPs of the exporters to the `static_configs.targets` list like this:

```yaml
static_configs:
 - targets: [ "10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2", "10.0.0.3" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Prometheus is [pull-based](https://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/faq/#why-do-you-pull-rather-than-push). Your services have to be reachable from Prometheus instance.

If these three vms are only monitoring targets - consider using push-based monitoring tools, like Graphite.

If you have **no other way**, but to use Prometheus, and making services reachable from Prometheus instance is not feasable, you can install [Pushgateway](https://github.com/prometheus/pushgateway) "near" Prometheus instance, and reconfigure your services to push metric to it.

But this approach is [**not recommended**](https://prometheus.io/docs/practices/pushing/)!

```
   VM#1           VM#2                                           VM#3
+---------|     +------------+     +------------+     Proxy    +------------+
| Grafana | --> | Prometheus | --> | Pushgateway|  <---------- | Exporter#1 | 
+---------|     +------------+     +------------+    ^ ^       +------------+
                                                     | |
                                                     | |         VM#4
                                                     | |      +------------+
                                                     | +----- | Exporter#2 |
                                                     |        +------------+
                                                     |           VM#5
                                                     +------- +------------+
                                                              | Exporter#3 |
                                                              +------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone helping!

With the explaination of @markalex and @SIMULATAN, I adjusted my vm setup and finally decided to use a different `static_config` for each VM. And I found that `Grafana` can combine multiple queries into one graph, so "in frontend" these 3 VM's data can "combine" by `Grafana`

Thanks everyone